# Google Analytics track conversion but not general traffic

Tags: google-analytics

Having two sites: diffy.website and app itself app.diffy.website. I would like to track visitors on diffy.website but conversions (registrations) from the app. I have configured cross domain tracking, but I am getting traffic counts from the app as well. What is the best way to filter visits to my app but keep conversion events?

Comment: When you add the tracking code to your two sites, you can specify whether you want to trigger pageviews or events. Sounds like you need the pageview tracking code on the website, but just event/goal tracking on the app - without pageviews enabled.

Comment: @WebElaine oh that is interesting. How you can specify that I need events only?

Comment: It depends on how you have the tracking code enabled. One way is to use Google Tag Manager, and you can specify to just trigger events, or just trigger pageviews, or trigger both, for whichever site or app you have GTM installed on.